# Can't run android application via emulator

Tags: android, cordova, android-emulator, aptana

I have installed android sdk and JDK on aptana. Now I'm trying to create phonegap application but when I create new android project as it is described on phonegap website and try to run it I get an error that the .apk file could not be found. Here is the error log:

```
[2012-04-18 22:28:37 - androidApp] ------------------------------
[2012-04-18 22:28:37 - androidApp] Android Launch!
[2012-04-18 22:28:37 - androidApp] adb is running normally.
[2012-04-18 22:28:37 - androidApp] Could not find androidApp.apk!
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: not sure what the problem is, but for the time being, you could use adb to install the package manually<br>
"adb install packagedir/package.apk"

Comment: Doesn't work. I get the following error: $ adb install packagedir/package.apk
can't find 'packagedir/package.apk' to install

Comment: I meant for you to substitute "packagedir" with the location of the package on your harddrive.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html#move

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Guess it's time to answers this question myself :)

The solution to this problem was to export adb path using this command:

> export
>   PATH=$PATH{}:/path/to/android-sdk/tools:/path/to/android/platform-tools

After issuing this command the emulator was successfully launched and the apk file was generated as well.

Answer (score 0):

Well, i ran into the same problem. And what i just did, is 
1. stop currently running simulator
2. kill adb.exe
3. restart eclipse
4. re-run the project as Android application

I got it :)